# Javascript package or library for UI component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am looking for a implementation for the following image of a component. It runs through each header and text and scrolls up the associated image periodically. The user may also select a text block and the image on the right will scroll to the associated image, much like a carousel. Is there a library or package that may help me create this?

(I'm not sure what the best term for such an interface is)

[image: Image slider]

Comment: Questions asking for off site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check components from [this](http://jster.net/category/ui-frameworks#/ui) collection of JavaScript UI frameworks.